# Gta V isn't working

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I do not have internet at my house but i do got internet at my friends house, When i play gta at my non- internet house it says "You must be signed into xbox live to save your data and earn achievements." Xbox live or Xbox something when i'm already signed in.. Please help me?

Comment: Does this error message appear right when you start the game, or do you have to do something else to get it?

Answer (score -1):

You're 'signed in' internally but you still need the internet connection active at the time you play to be 'signed in externally' it's looking for the external sign in.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but how come i cant play without internet?

Comment: I'm not sure you can't - you just won't get the achievements and things. GTAV now tracks everything you do in the game and they sell that data, a lot of games are locking people out of offline mode so that they can do 'analytics' and such - it's stupid, but is what it is.